# Restriction function as a Morse function

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, gt.geometric-topology, surfaces

Let $\Sigma$ be a closed surface smoothly embedded in $\mathbb R^3$. For any Morse function $h:\mathbb R^3 \to \mathbb R$, can we isotope $\Sigma$ so that the restriction of $h$ on $\Sigma$ is also a Morse function?

Comment: No, of course not.  For example, what if $h$ is constant?

Comment: @RyanBudney I forgot to add that $h$ is a Morse function in $\mathbb R^3$.

Comment: Then I think the answer is yes.  Step (1) perturb the surface to be disjoint from the critical points of $h$.  Step (2) Use that $h$ is a submersion in a neighbourhood of the surface.  Specifically, $h$ restricted to the surface may not be Morse, but a small perturbation of it is.  Using the local triviality of $h$ near the surface allows you to perturb the surface, using the flow of a vector field, to mimic the perturbation of a non-Morse function to a Morse function.